# How to generate multiply row in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table as below:

```
Entity  counts
A       4
B       2
C       2
D       5
```

I want to generate more rows from that table by adding 1 column named `order`. This column value is the countdown of the `counts` column. The table I want to create as below:

```
Entity  counts  order
A       4       3
A       4       2
A       4       1
A       4       0
B       2       1
B       2       0
C       2       1
C       2       0
D       5       4
D       5       3
D       5       2
D       5       1
D       5       0
```

Please help me on this one. Thanks

Comment: Please format your question properly. Nothing is understandable.

Comment: can you specify the code which you tried? and mention here properly..So that i can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

- first duplicated values of index by [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) and by `loc` repeat rows
- for order column use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) by index
- last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for default non duplicated index

---

```
df = df.loc[np.repeat(df.index, df['counts'])]
df['order'] = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(ascending=False)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   Entity  counts  order
0       A       4      3
1       A       4      2
2       A       4      1
3       A       4      0
4       B       2      1
5       B       2      0
6       C       2      1
7       C       2      0
8       D       5      4
9       D       5      3
10      D       5      2
11      D       5      1
12      D       5      0
```